# Is hysteresis essential for a memory system or material?

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, material-science, electronics

I want to know whether its essential for a memory system or material to have hysteresis between two of its variable? If Yes, what can be the general relation of volatility of a memory with its hysteresis loop?

Comment: I haven't quite understood what you are asking exactly... Perhaps you can clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Any memory system requires that the dependent variable should retain the information even after the independent variable(input) has changed. If by Hysteresis you mean only magnetic hysteresis then that might not be the essential component of a memory device. Most of the computers use flip flops as memory storage units. They are just clever circuits made out of transistors which stores data in binary form.

But if hysteresis based memory devices would be made then surely its efficiency will be based on the retaintivity of the material used. For that we'd have to use hard ferromagnetics but they will again be hard to magnetize so storing of data would be difficult.